# Run a Stored Procedure via a click of a button in .Net web page

Tags: sqlconnection, sqlcommand, asp.net-controls

Afternoon All,

I have a stored procedure in an SQL 2005 database named GasNominationsRawData_Insert.

When executed this simply extracts some data from another database and inserts the result into a table.  This query works fine.

What i need to do is enable this to be executed on the click on a button on my web page.  I have had a good luck around the internet have have managed to create the following code in my .net 2008 web page.  But i think im either missing something or i have have completly the wrong code.   Im new to programming in .Net but i understand that i need to delclare the stored procedure, create the SQL connection, create the command line, open the conection, execute the query and then close the connection.

I dont need or have any parameters.  Essentially this button is just used to push data to a table.

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class RawData
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub btnAddRawData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddRawData.Click

    'Declare Stored Procedure
    Dim GasNominationsRawData_Insert As String = "GasNominationsRawData_Insert"

    'Declare SQL Connection (This is the connection string located on the web.config page)
    Dim SQLConn As SqlConnection
    SQLConn = New SqlConnection("GasNominationsDataConnectionString")

    'Declare command
    Dim SqlComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GasNominationsRawData_Insert", SQLConn)
    SqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Try
        'Open SQL Connection
        SQLConn.Open()

        'Execute Query
        SqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'Close connection
        SQLConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw (ex)

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Any Help is much appreciated.

Regards Betty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upps. I overlooked that. You're trying to connect to your database with the connectionstring: "GasNominationsDataConnectionString". That's of course no correct connection string. 
Your connection string should look somehow like that: 
"Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" 
So you have to get your connection string first out of your web.config like
Dim GasNominationsDataConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GasNominationsDataConnectionString").ConnectionString

Regards
Anja

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine at a first glance. So what happens on clicking the button? Have you assured that your btnAddRawData_Click is called when the button is clicked?

Comment: when i click the button on the web page i get the following error message: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. and line 14 is highlighted red: SQLConn = New SqlConnection("GasNominationsDataConnectionString").  I thought that this was an issue with the connection string in the Web config file but this connection sting is used else where in the web app for a grid view and works just fine?